# Create a control based on value in a DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to create a dynamically built page in my ASP.NET app (using VB). The page collects parameter information for a report.

The report information such as the name, stored procedure and the required parameters are in a DB table.

In the table I have a field 'control_type' which I am hoping I can use to be the type of control I need to create to collect the relevant parameter value for the selected report.
So, if I select Report01, I get the row form the DB for Report01 and the parameter data for that reports row tells me I need to collect an integer value into a parameter called i_company_id and the control to create to select this value form (on my dynamically created parameters page) says 'DropDownList'.

If I get the row from the DB and place that filed value into a variable, can I then do something like

```
dim ddl as New VaraibleName
```

and then I can populate the list as normal and then

```
panel.controls.add(ddl)
```

The key bit is being able to create a control where the type of control to create is in a variable or some other dynamically defined way.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the following solution delivers what you want:

```
Private Function createVariable(inputName As String) As Object
    Dim outVariable As Object = New Object

    If (inputName = "DropDownList") Then
        Dim targetVariable As DropDownList = New DropDownList()
        With targetVariable
            'You might change here its properties (passed via Object array for example)
        End With

        outVariable = targetVariable
    End If
    'Add as many conditions as variables you are expecting

    Return outVariable
End Function
```

Call it by doing:

```
Dim ddl As Object = createVariable("VariableName")
panel.Controls.Add(ddl)
```

If you are planning to use this code just with `Controls`, you can replace `Object` with `Control` (will work either way).

Comment: Lovely idea! Thanks very much.